# 14.04 No Wi fi & Ethernet after Lighting

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I have 14.04 with an I3 & Skylake GT2 and a Thompson Gateway TG782T Telecom Australia modem.

I was logging on when a lighting struck close-by. We have 4 other computers, none of these were effected, all wireless except me. I have unplugged from the modem as I had a continuous loop trying to log on and disconnecting.

Is there a way I can test my connection or can I buy a replacement network card as I'm just a user, not a Techie...

[terminal image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hyMa.png)

[Terminal Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoD39.png)

Comment: As you suggested, it seems like hardware failure, you might want to get help from PC technician.  Do you have Wifi on your PC? would you like to try using USB-Wifi dongle?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After some thought  I think a USB-Wifi may be the answer. Dave

Comment: added my comment as answer to your question, if it answer your needs please [accept](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested, it seems like hardware failure.

You can connect to the WIFI network using USB-Wifi dongle.